# Create FaceListId FaceAPI Microsoft Azure

Tags: angular, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

**What I'm using**

FaceAPI, AngularFire2, FireStore, Angular v6

**What I'm trying to do**

I want Find similar faces with photo in Firebase Storage, I have the DownloadURL to compare.

**Issue**

I do not know how to create the FaceListId, I do not understand the documentation.

https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039524b

**Observations**

I not idea as start. I have working FaceAPI - Detect but I need Find Similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Create FaceListId RestAPI](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039524b), we could use it to create an empty face list with user-specified faceListId, name and an optional userData.

```
put https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/facelists/{faceListId}
```

If you want to create a facelist you could use the API documentation for test.

```
PUT https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/facelists/tomtest HTTP/1.1
Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxx    
{

    "name": "tomtestlist",

    "userData": "it is optional"

}
```

Test Result:

[image]

If you need Find Similar, you could follow the blow steps:

1.The create facelistid RestAPi just create the empty list. We also need to [add face](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395250) into the facelist.

2.Use the [detect api](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) to get the faceid.

3.use the Find similar API

```
https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/findsimilars 

{
    "faceId": "faceid get from detect api",
    "largeFaceListId": "tomtest",
    "maxNumOfCandidatesReturned": 10,
    "mode": "matchPerson"
}
```

**Note:** Face list is a list of faces, up to 1,000 faces, please consider **LargeFaceList** when the face number is large. It can support up to 1,000,000 faces.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for answering. The workflow should be.

1. Create a Create FaceListId 
2. Add face to FaceListId with Detect
3. Use the FaceListId in Find similar

    "largeFaceListId": "tomtest" is optional? or I can use
    "faceListId": "tomtest" ? I only need few faces.